# mac os error installing PyQt while trying to make install

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt5

I was trying to install PyQt5, when I execute ' make && make install' ,this error occur.

```
install: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyQt5//QtCore.so: chmod: Operation not permitted
make[1]: [install_target] Error 71 (ignored)
mkdir: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/share/sip/PyQt5/QtCore: Operation not permitted
make[1]: *** [install_sip] Error 1
make: *** [sub-QtCore-install_subtargets-ordered] Error 2
```

Comment: Sudo it, maybe.

Comment: it does not work

Comment: I cannot mkdir in /System directory even use the sudo command. It is normal?

Comment: Actually, I can successfully install PyQt if I install it outside the /System directory

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the stupid question. The problem actually is I cannot get the highest permission even using sudo. Mac's system-level directory cannot be changed.